# Compilation Error in fortran: Invalid character in name at (1)

Tags: arrays, matlab, fortran

I have written a code in FORTRAN for conjugate gradient method... There is an error and i am not able to solve it after hours of working on it!
The attached code is a subroutine to do the CGR and it is part of my main program which consists of 2 functions and other subroutines.

```
!                       (C_F2,C2  ,C1  ,C_Fold,IG ,JG ,dCnew,converged)
    SUBROUTINE gcr_Mfree(F2  ,Cnew,Cold,C_Fold,IGG,JGG,x    ,converged)

        !**** FUNCTIONS TO BE SOLVED ****
        ! Generalized Conjugate Residual Algorithm
        ! Solves M*x=b (J*dx=-F)


        ! Use somemodule
        ! Arguments declarations
        IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)

        INTEGER :: IGG,JGG
        real*8, dimension(:), ALLOCATABLE :: x
        real*8, intent(out)                 :: converged  !<
        REAL*8, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: F2,F22,Cnew,Cold,C_Fold,p,Mp 

        ! Variable declarations
        real*8 :: alpha2,tol  
        real*8, DIMENSION(:),   ALLOCATABLE :: r,b,Mr,F2V,F22V,CnewV,ColdV,C_FoldV
        integer :: i,j,maxiter,AllocateStatus,normr

        MASK = SIZE(F2)
        ALLOCATE(F2V(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(CnewV(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(ColdV(1:MASK))
        ALLOCATE(C_FoldV(1:MASK))
        !*********** RESHAPING MATRICES TO VECTORS.........
        F2V    = RESHAPE(F2  ,(/MASK/))
        CnewV  = RESHAPE(Cnew,(/MASK/))
        ColdV  = RESHAPE(Cold,(/MASK/))
        C_FoldV = RESHAPE(C_Fold,(/MASK/))

        b       = -F2V                 !(why minus?)
        tol     = 5.E-2
        alpha2  = 1e-6 ! alpha2 is the epsilon in the report!
        maxiter = size(b)

        DEALLOCATE(x)
        ALLOCATE(x(1:maxiter))
        x       = 0.0D0       !GUIdE: ""m2f: x = zeros(maxiter,1)""


        r       = b ! we need this when calculating r_new
        ! normr(1) = norm2(r)                             !!!! Norm


        DO iter=1,maxiter

            !Get preliminary search direction

            DO i=1,iter
                p(:,i) = r
            ENDDO

            ! Approximate the Jacobian(M) residual product
            CnewV = CnewV + alpha2*r
            Cnew = RESHAPE(CnewV,(/IGG,JGG/))

            F22 = CNF2(Cnew,Cold,Fold,DT)
            F22V= RESHAPE(F22V,(/MASK/))

            Mr = (1/alpha2)*(F22V-F2V)      !GUIDE: (The apporximated Jacobian matrix)

            DO i=1,iter
                Mp(:,i) = Mr
            ENDDO

            !! Orthogonalize search direction
            do j=1,iter-1
          !m2f: p(:,iter) = p(:,iter) -  Mp(:,j)'* Mp(:,iter) * p(:,j)
                p(:,iter) = p(:,iter) -  Mp(j,:) * Mp(:,iter) * p(:,j)

          !m2f: Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) -Mp(:,j)'* Mp(:,iter) * Mp(:,j)
                Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) -Mp(j,:) * Mp(:,iter) * Mp(:,j)
            end do
            !norm(Mp(:,iter))

            !Normalize search direction
            p(:,iter)  =  p(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter)))
            Mp(:,iter) = Mp(:,iter) / (norm2(Mp(:,iter)))


            !Update solution and residual
            alpha2 = r * Mp(:,iter) / (Mp(iter,:)) * (Mp(:,iter)))

            x = x + alpha2 * p(:,iter)
            r = r - alpha2 * Mp(:,iter)      ! where is the *(Cnew - C)?


            !Check convergence
!!!!        normr=norm2(r)                               !!!! norm
            !fprintf('norm(r) = !g iter = !gNewLine',normr,iter+1);
            if (normr < tol) then
                !fprintf('GCR Converged, iter = !gNewLine',iter+1);
                converged=1
                exit
            end if


        END DO !for loop

        if (normr > tol) then
            write(*,*) 'GCR SOLUTION DID NOT CONVERGE!'
            converged=0
        end if

        RETURN
    END subroutine gcr_Mfree
```

I am compiling the subroutine separately to solve all issues. I solved the other errors, but I couldn't solve this one.

```
gfortran -Wall -c "gcr_Mfree.f95" (in directory: /home/vahid/Dropbox/To    Move folder/Geany)
gcr_Mfree.f95:85.34:
            alpha2 = r * Mp(:,iter) / (Mp(iter,:)) * (Mp(:,iter)))
                              1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
Compilation failed.
```

On the other hand, I want to know, how can I verify an arrays elements and shape? Specially where I use (:,iter) during the DO loop. I mean, the arrays are changing form vector to matrix at each iteration and the size of matrix is getting bigger at each iteration. 
I know I can print it at display after compilation. I want to be aware of the shape/elements of the array to be sure I am in the correct direction.

Comment: @francescalus There is no **iter** elsewhere in my code. I have added **iter** to INTEGER parameters list. But nothing changed.

Comment: You have unbalanced parenthesis on that line, is that a typo from pasting it here, or is your code really like that?

Comment: @francescalus I have changed to **IMPLICIT NONE**, But the error still exists.

Comment: @casey : Thanks for the eagle eyes. it solved the issue, However I am getting another error at the same row now. It is : **Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)**

Comment: In which case I'd agree with @casey that your parenthesis count would be the next place to look.  My comment was also spectacularly unhelpful as I convinced myself `iter` was implicit real based on ending in `r`...

Comment: Where is Mp allocated?

Comment: Regarding your new error, the LHS is a scalar, the RHS is not.

Comment: @Ross : No where. since I haven't received any error for **Mp** and **p** at previous rows. That is the reason that I am not allocating them but I should. maybe It is because of **norm2**. I need to write a function for finding Euclidean norm of matrices and vectors...

Comment: Writing to unallocated variables may not give you a compile time error, but it is undefined behavior and can cause runtime errors.  It is a violation of the standard (Fortran 2008 6.7.1.3) to define or reference an allocatable variable with "unallocated" status, which is the case until you allocate it.

Comment: @casey : I have allocated the variables using **ALLOCATE(p(1:IG,1:JG))** and **ALLOCATE(Mp(1:IG,1:JG))**... what do you mean by LHS and RHS? I googled them. They seem to be logical operators, right?

Comment: LHS is "left hand side", RHS is "right hand side" and they refer to the left and right side of the assignment (=).  You cannot assign a vector to a scalar, and that is what that line is attempting to do.

Comment: @casey : Thank you. You guys are real programmers and see the details very fast. **r** at RHS should be transposed to make RHS scalar.

Comment: I guess the line `Mp( :, iter ) = Mp( :, iter ) - Mp( j, : ) * Mp( :, iter ) * Mp( :, j )` should probably be replaced by `Mp( :, iter ) = Mp( :, iter ) - sum( Mp( :, j ) * Mp( :, iter ) ) * Mp( :, j )` because in the Matlab version an inner product appears in the orthogonalization (`Mp( : ,j )' * Mp( :, iter )`) Also, the exchange of column and row indices seems not necessary (i.e., Mp(:,j) -> Mp(j,:) is not necessary). Anyway I think putting matlab tag in the Question will be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As casey commented, and this solved your problem, your code is faulty because of the extra closing parenthesis.  It may be helpful to say one thing as an answer, though.

The error message you get from gfortran seems quite unhelpful as a diagnostic one.  Look at the very simplified version of your code (without full declarations, etc.)

```
  real, dimension(10,10) :: Mp
  alpha2 = r * Mp(:,iter) / (Mp(iter,:)) * (Mp(:,iter)))
end
```

and compile that.  With gfortran 4.9 I get a similar message to you:

```
alpha2 = r * Mp(:,iter) / (Mp(iter,:)) * (Mp(:,iter)))
                  1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Instead, using ifort I get the much more useful

```
  error #5276: Unbalanced parentheses
  alpha2 = r * Mp(:,iter) / (Mp(iter,:)) * (Mp(:,iter)))
-------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: AWESOME! but as far as I know IFORT is a paid compiler and there is no student or academic version. please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: There is a non-commercial licence of some form, but you'll have to look into details of that.  There are other compilers also, of course, which have varying degrees of diagnostic offerings, cost.  ifort just happened to be the one I had to hand.

Comment: @VahidAttari   There is a non-commercial free license for ifort and they may be re-introducing the Fortran compiler into the student license soon.

Comment: @francescalus agreed that error is terrible from gfortran.  I submitted a bug for the unhelpful message so maybe someday that message can be on-par with ifort...

Comment: @casey  I have checked Intel website. There is a **student version** available now. I am really happy for this. For instance, I need to calculate norm of a arrays which is available at 2008 standard as a intrinsic function. This is going to save time a lot.

Comment: `norm2` is available in gfortran too. @francescalus the free non-commercial version of ifort does not exist any more due to frequent misuse.

Comment: @VladimirF That's a shame about ifort, but good to know, thanks.